# Check if string in upper case

Tags: c#

I want to check if my string contains all the upper case value or not for that I am using the below code but It does not work as expected for case 1 and only work for case2.

Case 1

```
string myString = "SWEET POTATO";
myString.All(char.IsUpper)
```

Case 2

```
string eval = "POTATO";  
eval.All(char.IsUpper)
```

It does not give me any error but I want in both the cases it will return true because in both the cases string value is in Upper case letter

Comment: Because your case1 includes `space` in between SWEET and POTATO

Comment: Try `myString.Where(char.IsLetter).All(char.IsUpper)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert your String to Upcase and check eval:

```
string myString = "FOO BAR"
if (myString.ToUpper() == myString) {
    // your handling
}
```

Comment: While answering the question it is bad idea! Please don't create garbage just to check if string is all caps.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I appreciate your comment, but  can you please elaborate what is garbage here.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar string created as result of `myString.ToUpper()` becomes no longer referenced after that line and had to be garbage collected later... this may be ok for one-time operation on small string but quickly becomes a problem if this type of coding is used across big/long running system.